# .exe won't open in AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I want to install the .net Framework 3.5 offline on Windows 10 computers. The weird thing is that my installer (C:\DotNet_Win10.exe) doesn't start when I run this script:

```cpp
Func _Au3RecordSetup()
    Opt('WinWaitDelay', 100)
    Opt('WinDetectHiddenText', 1)
    Opt('MouseCoordMode', 0)

    Local $aResult = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetKeyboardLayoutNameW', 'wstr', '')
    If $aResult[1] <> '00000407' Then
        MsgBox(64, 'Warning', 'Recording has been done under a different Keyboard layout' & @CRLF & '(00000407->' & $aResult[1] & ')')
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _WinWaitActivate($title, $text, $timeout = 0)
    WinWait($title, $text, $timeout)
    If Not WinActive($title,$text) Then WinActivate($title, $text)
    WinWaitActive($title, $text, $timeout)
EndFunc

_AU3RecordSetup()

Run('C:\DotNet_Win10.exe')

_WinWaitActivate("DotNet for Windows 10 x86 x64 Setup","")

Send("{ENTER}")
Sleep(20000)
Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")

_WinWaitActivate("DotNet for Windows 10 x86 x64 Setup ","")

Send("{ENTER}")
```

The more important part is of course the lower part.

Why doesn't it open? When I run the .exe normally it just opens and the installation works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you try running it with administrator rights? This is really a potato solution to deploy .NET to computers. If at all it should be installed via the additional features in the software CP of Windows 10. The window title doesn't seem to come from an official setup by the way.

Comment: @Ray Koopa running it with administrator right doesn't do anything sadly. The option of additional features doesn't work with most of our PC, we would have to open up our Firewall rules for that and I'm not in charge to make this decision.

Comment: The other only official solution is to use the DISM tool together with a Windows 10 ISO / DVD / stick with which you run `Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:X:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess` (where X: is the drive letter of the ISO). Would that work out?

Comment: Sadly also no. We had this problem a few months ago and the decision fell that we will use this installer. And it always worked out, but we neeeded to get on the computer itself and install it. We want to let it run over AutoIT and Open pc server integration. But now the installer won't ppen via AutoIT..

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Maybe the installer is borked. As far as I know it doesn't look like anything official... have you tried not putting it in the root directory of C; and in a folder the user safely has even write access to? Not that it gets blocked by anything weird it wants to do.

Comment: Yes I already put it in different locations. I am also an administrator and have write access to every file on C: 
The installer normally runs fine, I don't get why it shouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even while I don't know exactly why `Run()` doesn't work here, you can try using `ShellExecute()` instead.